# Windows 7 backup network restore: "The network location cannot be reached, 0x800704CF"

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, networking, backup, restore

When I try to restore from a backup image, I get this error.

[image: windows 7 backup restore]

After I enter the network address (`\\10.0.0.1\backup` or `\\z\backup`), the wizard presents me with the network login dialog, which leads me to believe that it can connect to the network (yes, the share is password protected).

I decided to install Windows 7, since I thought that I could restore the image from Windows. The restore process in Windows can locate the backups, but to do an image restore it needs to reboot to the wizard above. Which of course gives the very same error.

This is what `\\z\backup` looks like.

[image]

Please help, I'm getting desperate.

Update: Forgot to mention that the NAS is running Ubuntu, if that's relevant.

Comment: also, if not my answer, maybe [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2009/02/04/windows-server-backup-2008-restore-from-network-location.aspx) will help

Answer (score 1):

I've just had the same issue - turns out the restore utility didn't have the driver for my network card.

Install the driver (go back one step and select the install drivers option) then try again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Windows Image Restore does not have all required drivers for (some?) LAN Networking devices.

I encountered this problem myself and had to use third party software to restore from the backup.

I used [Acronis True Image 2013](http://kb.acronis.com/content/14297) (and it has a linxux-based restore environment :) [don't worry if you're not a linux user, it has a windows-like GUI to restore backups] ).

Answer (score -1):

On the PC that has the backup file, reboot when done.

> "Device Manager > Network Adapters > and there I've deleted everything"
>   That's the part that works. But first of all on device manager you must press 'view' -> 'show hidden devices'. After that small list of 2 or 3 devices is growing to about ~200devices. Unistall all of them (some can't be, don't bother). Then press right mouse button at any adapter and check 'scan for new devices'.

[Source of Information](http://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/113133-0x800704cf-error.html#post974683)

Comment: I don't think there is a device manager in the restore console. Are you sure you understand the question?

Comment: "On the PC that has the backup file" you are accessing another PC on the network right? That is the PC that needs to be fixed.

Comment: @Moab But that PC is running Ubuntu

Comment: You might edit your original post to include this new information, and add the Ubuntu tag also.

Comment: Don't see how it's relevant, but sure.

Comment: Its relevant because most likely the problem is with the PC hosting the backup file, which in this case is running Ubuntu.